# Filter Product Name in RetailProductDiscount Form productLookup ax 2012

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to add the field of ProductName filterable in the ProductLookup field in retailPeriodicDiscount form. It is strongly connected to EcoResProduct and I can't use any other lookup field or method.

So, I need to add the product name field to productLookup method. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For the product name you have to add the field `Name` of the table `EcoResProductTranslation` .Add the table as a joined datasource to the query and filter it by the system language.

```
sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(EcoResProduct, DisplayProductNumber));
sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(EcoResProduct, SearchName));
sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(EcoResProduct, ProductType));
sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(EcoResProductTranslation, Name));

if (_groupMember.Category)
{
    query = RetailGroupMemberLineQueryProvider::containedProductsQuery(_groupMember.Category, true /*includesubcategories*/, _dataAreaId);
}
else
{
    query = RetailGroupMemberLineQueryProvider::containedProductsQuery(_groupMember.Category, true /*includesubcategories*/, _dataAreaId);
}

// add datasources and join
qbdsProduct = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(EcoResProduct));
qbdsProductTranslation = qbdsProduct.addDatasource(tableNum(EcoResProductTranslation));
qbdsProduct.relations(true);
// range for system language
qbdsTranslation.addRange(fieldNum(EcoResProductTranslation, LanguageId)).value(SystemParameters::getSystemLanguageId());

sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
```

Comment: Thank you,I tried this,but it displays only one product and does not show the product Name but the SearchName,  and I do not understand why.